# Alternate way of this Query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say we have a Table named Employee with column 'Name':

```
+---------+
| Name    |
+---------+
| Jack    |
+---------+
| Paul    |
+---------+
| Jack    |
+---------+
```

To have the distinct name we can run this query:

```
Select DISTINCT Name 
from Employee
```

Is there any other way to retrieve the distinct value?

Comment: There is a lot of other ways. This is the best one.

Comment: Why? Your query is the standard way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Select Name 
from Employee
Group by Name
```

This also gives same result

Answer (score 5):

`GROUP BY` is silly, but `UNION` is even worse:

```
select name from Employee
union
select name from Employee
```

You can also do `INTERSECT`...

Comment: Take all names from table, and add them one more time using UNION. Since UNION removes result duplicates, each name will only be returned once!

Answer (score 4):

I don't know why you don't want to use distinct but you can `GROUP BY`

```
Select Name 
from Employee
group by Name;
```

If you just want to have some fun:

```
select top 1 with ties Name
from Employee
order by ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by Name order by Name)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;with #temp(Select Name,row_number()over(partition by name order by name desc) as seq)
Select Name from #temp where seq=1
```

Comment: Hi Mani; your code might be correct, but it would make a better answer with some context; for example, you could explain how and why this proposed change would resolve the questioner's problem, perhaps including a link to the relevant documentation. That would make it more useful to them, and also more useful to other site readers who are looking for solutions to similar problems.